# Change Font Size of entered text on PDF in Preview 9.0

Tags: macos, pdf, preview, font

I've read several similar questions but they appear to be outdated.  Many mentioned a "show fonts" option in the "Tools" menu which does not exist.  Others mention a couple ways to show the markup toolbar, which does include a font formatting option, but changing these options does absolutely nothing to the text I'm entering. I've tried highlighting existing entered text and modifying the values, and I've tried changing the values before entering new text. Nothing seems to be working, and my text is far too large to fit on the field I'm trying to fill out.

Any other ways of changing the font size that I'm not seeing? Is this maybe a bug with this version that'll be patched soon?

Thanks.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In the markup toolbar, all you have to do is add a text box and then any text will be customizable using the text formatting options

[image]

Comment: So there isn't a way to do this with the text fields that are already set up on the PDF I'm trying to fill out? I'd have to add my own new ones?

Comment: I don't know because I did not have any PDF documents with fields like you are mentioning, that I could try this with.  I used the only PDF document that I had that was close enough to answer your question

Comment: I'm gonna leave the question open a while longer to see if someone can address the pre-existing field issue.  If not, I'll mark this as since I could use it at the very least to get my PDF in a printable state. Thanks for your help.

Comment: Upvote for the lovely gif. =)

Comment: Sorry for the long delay in marking it as correct! A pain but it worked for me, and nobody else ever provided an alternative solution.

Comment: @wch1zpink Try to use this [PDF](https://www.postalidph.com/uploads/5/8/5/0/58500909/pid_app_form_w_gen_terms__1_.pdf) right here. That is fillable when opened with macOS Preview app. You can see when you hover above the blank lines.